# Python ImportError : cannot find symbol - for custom C++ module

Tags: python, cython

I have created 2 modules in C++ and imported them in Python via Cython.
The first module is called Generator and it contains 2 classes : MersenneTwister, which implements algorithms for generating pseud-random numbers and a Generator class which is a singleton, creating a MersenneTwister object.
The second module is called  KMeans and contains a function calls KMeans implementing the K-Means algorithm for clustering data.
For both modules I have created the corresponding .pyx files, which where compiles OK by cython and then, using g++ I have created the .so files and then imported the KMeans.so files in python, receiving : ImportError: ./KMeans.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9Generator8instanceEv

I have compiles the .cpp files using : g++ -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -o  file.so file.cpp

```
# KMeans.pyx files 

include "Generator.pyx"
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cdef import from "KMeans.h" :

           cdef struct Pair:

               vector[vector[double]] C
               vector[unsigned int] J

               Pair(vector[vector[double]] _C, vector[unsigned int] _J)

           cdef double s(vector[double] X, vector[double] c)
           cdef void   AddToCodeword(vector[double] X, vector[double] c)
           cdef Pair KMeans(unsigned int k, vector[vector[double]] X) except +

def KMean(unsigned k, X):

   cdef Pair returnValue = KMeans(k, X)

   return returnValue.C, returnValue.J

#Generator.pyx file


cdef extern from "mt.h":

    cppclass MersenneTwister:

       MersenneTwister()

       #public members
       double random() 
       void init_genrand(unsigned long s)
       void init_by_array(unsigned long* init_key, int key_length)
       unsigned long genrand_int32()
       long genrand_int31()
       double genrand_real1()
       double genrand_real2()
       double genrand_real3()
       double genrand_res53()

       #private members
       unsigned long* mt_
       int mti_
       unsigned long* init_key_
       int key_length_ 
       unsigned long s_
       int seeded_by_array_ 
       int seeded_by_int_

#static members
cdef extern from "mt.h" namespace "MersenneTwister":

       int N                    = 624
       int M                    = 397
       unsigned long MATRIX_A   = 0x9908b0dfUL
       unsigned long UPPER_MASK = 0x80000000UL
       unsigned long LOWER_MASK = 0x7fffffffUL

cdef extern from "generator.h" namespace "Generator":

    MersenneTwister *_ptr_
    MersenneTwister *instance()
    MersenneTwister *instance(unsigned int seed)
```

Comment: FWIW: The python stdlib [`random` module](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) uses Mersenne Twister as the default generator. Doesn't fix your problem, but would perhaps avoid some of it..

Comment: Yes, I know about random module, the problem is that I need to call the pseudo-random number generator from C++ code and to that the generator to be unique while running the program (that is why I have create the Generator singleton class)